# TikZ axis label (t) at the right of axis

Tags: pgfplots

I'm stacked with t node at x-axis. But that not happen to F at y-axis. Can you enlighten me whats wrong with my code here
I need to place the "t" at most right of x-axis

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{axis}[
axis x line=center,
ylabel={$y$},
xlabel={$t$}, 
axis y line=middle,
every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.north west)},above=2mm}, 
xtick={0,9.42 },
xticklabels={0,{2 s}},
ytick={-1,0,1},
yticklabels={-2m, 0,2m},
xmin=.0, xmax=9.6,
domain=0:3.34*pi, width=10cm,height=4cm,
samples=41,grid]
\addplot[thick, red, no marks] {sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a change in your option `every axis y label`

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
    \begin{axis}[
      axis x line=center,
      ylabel={$y$},
      xlabel={$t$}, 
      axis y line=middle,
      every axis y label/.style={
        at={(ticklabel* cs:1.2)},
        anchor=north,
      },
      every axis x label/.style={
        at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
        anchor=east,
      },
      xtick={0,9.42 },
      xticklabels={0,{2 s}},
      ytick={-1,0,1},
      yticklabels={-2m, 0,2m},
      xmin=.0, xmax=9.6,
      domain=0:3.34*pi, width=10cm,height=4cm,
      samples=41,grid]
      \addplot[thick, red, no marks] {sin(deg(x))};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, what about cs at ticklabel* means?

Comment: @arif.stwan `ticklabel cs` is a coordinate system associated with tick labels